# Long to binary string as 64 bit and adding it to 8x8 array

Tags: java, 2d

Say, I have a binary string like

```
11110001000010100000011000000110000001100000010100001000111100
```

it's `62` bits and I want it to be `64`

```
0011110001000010100000011000000110000001100000010100001000111100
```

I can print it as 64, but how do I save it so I can add it to the array?

```
for(int i = 0; i < Long.numberOfLeadingZeros((long)num); i++) {
            System.out.print('0');
        }
        System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString((long)num));
```

Also I want to add in the 2D array so I can display it as 8x8

```
00111100
01000010
10000001
10000001
10000001
10000001
01000010
00111100
```

This is my code to add it to the array,

```
for(int i = 0; i < bin1.length(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
                for(int z = 0; z < 8; z++){
                    table[j][z] = bin1.charAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
```

but when I print it, it just prints `0`s.

```
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
```

Comment: Each iteration of your outermost loop is filling every cell in the table with the charAt(i).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
long num = 4342175383962075708L;
char[][] table = new char[8][8];
String bin1 = Long.toUnsignedString(num, 2);

while(bin1.length()<64){
  bin1="0"+bin1;
}
//Store the bits in the array
int i=0;
for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
    for(int z = 0; z < 8; z++){
        table[j][z] = bin1.charAt(i++);
    }
}
//Print the numbers
for(char[] m : table){
  for(char n : m){
    System.out.print(n);
  }
  System.out.println()
}
```

Comment: Please, First explain what went wrong and then provide the solution. This will help others to understand better. Thanks!

Comment: can u please explain.

Answer (score 0):

using below to save it as 2d array that you want:

```
int j=0,z =0;
for(int i = 0; i < Long.numberOfLeadingZeros((long)num); i++) {
        System.out.print('0');
        table[j][z++] = '0';
        if(z>7){
           j++;
           z=0;
        }
}

String a = Long.toBinaryString((long)num);
for(int g = 0; g < a.length(); g++){
        table[j][z++] = a.charAt(g);
        System.out.print(a.charAt(g));
        if(z>7){
           j++;
           z=0;
        }
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    for(int k = 0; k < 8; k++){
        for(int s = 0; s < 8; s++){
            System.out.print(table[k][s]);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```